# waiting for the result of the subscription then send data after

Tags: angular, firebase, observable

I am using angular to connect to firebase and I want to get the data from array property, then push to the array the new data and finally send the updated array to database after

first I tried to do something like

```
this.dataService.getPostById(post['id']).subscribe(data => {
      commentArr = data['comments']
      commentArr.push(comment)
     this.dataService.updatePost(post, {comments: commentArr})
    })
```

but I am getting infinite loop as I am putting observable inside subscription function

Answer (score 0):

Use `take` operator

```
addComment(post, comment) {
  this.dataService.getPostById(post['id'])
  .pipe(take(1))
  .subscribe(() => {
     const comments = data['comments']
     comments.push(comment)
     this.dataService.updatePost(post, {comments: comments})
  })
}
```

Comment: The value of post is send from html to ts file through the function as I am looping over the posts in the html and sending the related post. In case I put the post in ngOnInit, how the post will be recognized?

Comment: is that useful?

Comment: I solved the issue, but I think this is a great idea, I'll try it also